A formula for the tangent
Consider the following formula
\begin{equation*}
    \beta = \tan \left( \frac{\pi}{2} - \varphi \right) \frac{1}{2} (p-q) + \sqrt{\frac{1}{4} \tan^2 \left( \frac{\pi}{2} - \varphi \right) (p-q)^2 - pq }.
\end{equation*}
In the special case that $p = -q$ we get
\begin{equation*}
    \beta = \tan \left( \frac{\pi}{2} - \varphi \right) p + \sqrt{\tan^2 \left( \frac{\pi}{2} - \varphi \right) p^2 + p^2 },
\end{equation*}
which we can rewrite as
\begin{equation*}
    \beta = p \left( \tan \left( \frac{\pi}{2} - \varphi \right) + \sqrt{\tan^2 \left( \frac{\pi}{2} - \varphi \right) + 1}\right).
\end{equation*}
Which is in fact equal to
\begin{equation*}
    \beta = p \tan \left(\frac{\pi}{2} - \frac{\varphi}{2}\right).
\end{equation*}
Can the original formula be rewritten into a nice compact formula for the more general case $pq < 0$? I would really like to get rid of the square root and the square in the original formula.

I don't think you'll get a nice formula outside of some edge cases like $p=0, q=0$ or similar to the one you pointed out ($p=q$ will give you a very nice formula :)

An obvious first step is to replace $\tan \left( \frac{\pi}{2} - \varphi \right)$ with $\cot(\varphi)$.

If you're OK not having an explicit formula for $\beta$, then $\beta^2 - \beta(p-q)\cot(\varphi) + pq = 0$ will work.

Use $$\cot (2 x)+ \sqrt{\cot ^2(2 x)+1} =\cot x$$

What's the context of this expression? If it represents some geometric configuration, there may be something about it that suggests how the expression "wants" to be written. ... As-is, I don't see a way to remove the square root. However, you can write this as $$\frac12(p-q)\left(
\tan\theta+\sigma\sqrt{\sec^2\theta-\left(\frac{p+q}{p-q}\right)^2}\right)$$ where $\theta:=\pi/2-\phi$ and $\sigma:=\operatorname{sign}(p-q)$. (If $pq<0$, then $\sigma=\operatorname{sign}(p)$.) Moreover, you can write $$\frac{p+q}{p-q}=\tan\left(\frac\pi4+\psi\right)$$ where $\psi:=\tan^{-1}\frac{q}{p}$.
